# Transfer files between pc and pocket-pc on the same network

Tags: file-transfer, windows-mobile, pocket-pc

What is the easiest way to transfer files from (and into) my pc to(from) my windows mobile  pocket-pc (Tytn II) just by using the wifi I have at home?
Is there any simple app that I can install on the pc or the pocket-pc that helps me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows CE (Pocket PC) version of  [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/ce.htm) has windows file sharing access in it, I think you access it through the \Plugins\LAN folder that is visible in Total Commander.  You may have to add a server first by specifying an address (machine name) and login credentials (standard windows username etc) but after that I think it works quite well and you can access the shared files with relative ease.

Total Commander is a very capable file browser on WinMo, much more useful than the builtin Explorer.